# JavaFx KeyEvent on Rectangle doesn't work

Tags: java, events, javafx, keyevent

I have a `Rectangle` on a `GridPane` and after adding `KeyEvent`, it doesn't fire.
this is my code:

```
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
    rectangle.setX(500.0f); 
    rectangle.setY(200.0f); 
    rectangle.setWidth(400.0f); 
    rectangle.setHeight(300.0f); 

    //add key event
    rectangle.setOnKeyTyped(event->{
       System.out.println("TYPED - Character: "+event.getCharacter()+
    ", Code: " + event.getCode() +
     ", Text: " +event.getText());
   });

    GridPane.setRowIndex(rectangle, 0);
    GridPane.setColumnIndex(rectangle, 0);
    gridPane.getChildren().add(rectangle);
```

Pressing any key does not print anything. What could be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Rectangle doesn't have focus and KeyEvents doesn't trigger on Nodes which doesn't have focus. You can ask for focus by invoking `rectangle.requestFocus()`. 
It seems by simply clicking on it wont get focus so you have to give it "manually".
If you don't want to get on click you can decide when do you want to get the Rectangle the focus and after it gets the focus, it would trigger the keyEvents too.

The onClick I mentioned would look like this:

`rectangle.setOnMouseClicked(event -> rectangle.requestFocus());`